# WPF Call Event handler from Style in Xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, controltemplate

I'm working on a custom WPF combobox control with a template shown in the image below.

[image]

As you can see, there is a TextBox (for filtering) and a button (for creating new record). So I create the class AdvComboBox with two events **Search**, **CreateNew**. My question is : How to call the handlers in the AdvComboBox class of these events from the control template ?

```
public class AdvComboBox : ComboBox
{
    public event TextChangedEventHandler Search;

    protected virtual void OnSearch(TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextChangedEventHandler handler = Search;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, e);
    }


    public event EventHandler CreateNew;

    protected virtual void OnCreateNew()
    {
        EventHandler handler = CreateNew;

        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

The Popup Part :

```
<Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="True" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsOpen="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Margin="1" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.ComboBoxPopupAnimationKey}}" Placement="Bottom">
                            <themes:SystemDropShadowChrome x:Name="shadow" Color="Transparent" MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}" MinWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=templateRoot}">
                                <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowFrameBrushKey}}" BorderThickness="1" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}">

                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="35"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="35"/>
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0"
                                                    Orientation="Horizontal">

                                            <!--TODO : Should Call OnSearch-->
                                            <TextBox Width="230"
                                                     Margin="5 0 0 0"
                                                     Height="26"
                                                     VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
                                            </TextBox>
                                        </StackPanel>

                                        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" x:Name="DropDownScrollViewer">
                                            <Grid x:Name="grid" RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                                <Canvas x:Name="canvas" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0">
                                                    <Rectangle x:Name="OpaqueRect" Fill="{Binding Background, ElementName=DropDownBorder}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=DropDownBorder}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=DropDownBorder}"/>
                                                </Canvas>
                                                <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </ScrollViewer>

                                        <StackPanel Grid.Row="2"
                                                    Margin="5">

                                            <!--TODO : Should Call OnCreateNew-->
                                            <Button Content="Create new record"
                                                    Name="BnCreateNew"
                                                    Width="Auto"
                                                    Padding="3"
                                                    HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                                            </Button>

                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Border>
                            </themes:SystemDropShadowChrome>
                        </Popup>
```

AdvComboBox in Xaml

```
<local:AdvComboBox 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Width="250"
        Height="30"
        VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
        Style="{DynamicResource AdvComboBoxStyle1}"
        Search="AdvComboBox_OnSearch"
        CreateNew="AdvComboBox_OnCreateNew">

        <ComboBoxItem Content="Item 1"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Item 2"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Item 3"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Item 4"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Item 5"/>
    </local:AdvComboBox>
```

**EDIT :**

After reading the msdn article provided in @Marco response, I've used Routed events to solve my problem by subscribing to the `TextBox.TextChanged` event and `Button.Click` event. Some little logic were necessary in the Button.Click handler to differentiate between the click on the `ToggleButton` and the simple `Button` (Create new record).

```
<local:AdvComboBox 
        x:Name="CbCountries"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Width="250"
        Height="30"
        VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
        Style="{DynamicResource AdvComboBoxStyle1}"
        TextBox.TextChanged = "AdvComboBox_OnSearch"
        Button.Click = "AdvComboBox_OnCreateNew"/>
```

Handlers

```
private void AdvComboBox_OnCreateNew(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.OriginalSource is ToggleButton)
            return;

        MessageBox.Show("Create new record !", "Hello");
    }

private void AdvComboBox_OnSearch(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var combobox = sender as AdvComboBox;
        if (combobox == null)
            return;

        var textBox = e.OriginalSource as TextBox;
        if (textBox == null)
            return;

        var itemsViewOriginal = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(combobox.ItemsSource);

        itemsViewOriginal.Filter = (o =>
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox.Text))
                return true;

            if (((string)o).Contains(textBox.Text))
                return true;

            return false;
        });

        itemsViewOriginal.Refresh();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to cleare the events as RoutedEvents, the same way you need DependencyProperty. Something like this:

```
public static readonly RoutedEvent SearchEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(
    "Search", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(AdvComboBox));

// Provide CLR accessors for the event
public event RoutedEventHandler Search
{
        add { AddHandler(SearchEvent , value); } 
        remove { RemoveHandler(SearchEvent, value); }
}
```

Creating coltrols is not that simple. You need also to add a template for your control. And add a static constructor:

```
    static AdvComboBox ()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(AdvComboBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(AdvComboBox)));
    }
```

And, add some attributes like:

```
    [TemplatePart(Name = "PART_EditableTextBox", Type = typeof(TextBox))]
    [TemplatePart(Name = "PART_Popup", Type = typeof(Popup))]
    [TemplatePart(Name = "PART_CreateNewButton", Type = typeof(Button))]
    [TemplatePart(Name = "PART_SearchTextBox ", Type = typeof(TextBox))]
    [StyleTypedProperty(Property = "ItemContainerStyle", StyleTargetType = typeof(ComboBoxItem))] 
public class AdvComboBox : ComboBox
{ ...
```

Check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295235.aspx for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your help. After reading the msdn article, I've came to understand Routed events. And used them to solve my problem in a simple manner. I'll edit my question to include the solution.